# create a mat file that appends structure data using MATLAB C APIs

Tags: c, matlab

Am currently trying to create a **C** applications that could write a MAT file using the MATLAB C API.
Below is the reference code.

I have a `structure people` inside `structure family`. and the number of `struct family` data is dynamic i.e. the size can vary.

Writing a known size of `struct family`  works with simple change in the code in `writecomplexstructure` function

i want to create a function writecomplexstructure that could write data to matfile for every family `struct family` member

```
struct people {
    int age;
    int phone_number;
    int id;
};

struct family {
    int flatno;
    people family_members[3];
};

void writecomplexstructure(MATFile*  mat, int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[], int i, family family_data) {

    int flatno, family_members;
    static bool once = false;


    const char* field_names[] = { "flatno", "family_members" };
    mwSize dims[2] = { 1, 1 };
    plhs[0] = mxCreateStructArray(2, dims, 2, field_names);
    once = true;
    
    

    /* Create a 1-by-n array of structs. */

    flatno = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0], "flatno");
    family_members = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0], "family_members");

    mxArray* flatno_value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    *mxGetDoubles(flatno_value) = family_data.flatno;

    mxArray* family_value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
       

    mwSize dims1[2] = { 1,3 };

    const char* field_names_2[] = { "age","phone_number","id" };

    mxArray* structure_value = mxCreateStructArray(2, dims1, 3, field_names_2);

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        mxArray* age_value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
        mxArray* phone_value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
        mxArray* id_value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);

        *mxGetDoubles(age_value) = family_data.family_members[j].age;
        *mxGetDoubles(phone_value) = family_data.family_members[j].phone_number;
        *mxGetDoubles(id_value) = family_data.family_members[j].id;

        int age_field = mxGetFieldNumber(structure_value, "age");
        int phone_number_field = mxGetFieldNumber(structure_value, "phone_number");
        int id_field = mxGetFieldNumber(structure_value, "id");

        mxSetFieldByNumber(structure_value, j, age_field, age_value);
        mxSetFieldByNumber(structure_value, j, phone_number_field, phone_value);
        mxSetFieldByNumber(structure_value, j, id_field, id_value);

    }

   
        mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[i], 0, flatno, flatno_value);
        mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[i], 0, family_members, structure_value);
    
}

int main()
{
    MATFile* pmat;
    const char* file = "mattest1.mat";
    char str[256];
    int status;

    printf("Creating file %s...\n\n", file);
    pmat = matOpen(file, "w");
    if (pmat == NULL) {
        printf("Error creating file %s\n", file);
        printf("(Do you have write permission in this directory?)\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct family family_data[] = { {200, {{30, 12345, 1},{31, 23456, 2},{0,0,0}}},
                                {201, {{30, 45235, 1},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}} ,
                                {202, {{30, 98253, 1},{31, 11924, 2},{32,10022,0}}},
                                {203, {{30, 99922, 1},{31, 22299, 2},{0,0,0}}}, 
                                {204, {{30, 99922, 1},{31, 22299, 2},{0,0,0}}}, 
                                {205, {{30, 99922, 1},{31, 22299, 2},{0,0,0}}} };


    //mxArray* phs = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    const mxArray* phr = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    mxArray* phs = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        
        writecomplexstructure(pmat, 1, &phs, 0, &phr, i, family_data[i]);

        status = matPutVariable(pmat, "LocalDouble", phs);

        if (status != 0) {
            printf("%s :  Error using matPutVariable on line %d\n",
                __FILE__, __LINE__);
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        
    }
    mxDestroyArray(phs);
    if (matClose(pmat) != 0) {
        printf("Error closing file %s\n", file);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
}
```

Please help!